# Filtering HBase table on a key of type struct using Hive

Tags: hbase, hiveql, hadoop2

I have created the following HBase table using Hive as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE HBWeather (key struct<USAF:INT, WBAN:INT, `Date`:STRING>, TEMP INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '~' 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,T:Temp')
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="HBWeather", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable"="HBWeather");
```

then fill it with data:

```
Insert overwrite table HBWeather select NAMED_STRUCT('USAF',USAF, 'WBAN',WBAN,'Date', `Date`) key, TEMP from weather;
```

running the following returns the expected result:

```
select * from hbweather limited 10;
```

**Now my question is, how can I filter by a specific key when my key is struct?** for example if I want to find the TEMP where USAF is 400010, wban is 99999, and date = '200906280000', how to write that?... **how the where clause will look like when filtering on a key of type struct?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from hbweather where key.usaf=400010 and key.wban=99999 and key.`date`='199906280000' limit 10;
```